# Load Javascript with Magento Block template

Tags: javascript, php, html, magento

I have put javascript into a custom payment method block template .phtml like so:

```
<ul class="form-list" id="payment_form_<?php echo $this->getMethodCode() ?>" style="display:none;">
  <div>
       <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
...
   //]]>
    </script>
    </div>
</ul>
```

the Javascript controls the disabling and showing of input fields in my custom payment method form.

But the script does not load when my payment method custom form appears.

I was able to place the script into the head of the checkout html page using layout block reference. 
But that does not work since the payment method custom form is loaded after the JS is loaded.

I'm just trying to load the JS with the form, but that does not work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

- `alert('here') / console.log('here')` in the script to make sure it got called.
- wrap your script in:

  document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
  // your scripts
  }

To make sure it load last.